# How to define an interface's keys to be equivalent to a certain union type

Tags: typescript

I have this interface and a union type with "result types":

```
export interface ResponseData {
   products: string[];
   content: string[];
} 

export type resultTypes = 'categories'| 'products'| 'content'| 'files';
```

The `resultTypes` constitute the possible properties of the `ResponseData`.

How can I add to the definition of `ResponseData` to say that it can be dynamic in the sense that its keys must be one or more of the `resultTypes`?

I tried to create another interface which it would extend, where the keys where dynamic but I didn't succeed.

I have an **[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJWAGdIkjgARTGTOAbwCg5mwoIATAV2xiIC44RGFGQBzANoBdANxNm2CCmAoBQkUgkyGAXzgMGoSLDgwAnmDxRinADYwAKueJwAvHADk2asFHQExdwAfD1YObl4gjwUlFEj3dAQbANkGaKE4KxJFcgFCLLJKalo3OlCuHn44cXcod0kAGjho1BUqmrrtVOz4bE4oKxQ82wcnIlc4AHkAIwArYB4AOgBrYFMiAApM0nIASjhMMczhxwsiKRSzCxMnAAU2C1hTcZXTCHRrizeM4m3gFLT4AALA5DOxECboE54NzrS7AO4QMACOEIh5mPYuAB89DkVhgfSQH3h90QhK22TwADJKd98uRxCj7lptP9ukTUeNev1lDBQSNTuIAAxaAGIIgANUwNgQ7HGwKIfPBkKcsNu9x20iAA)** here. I pass a "typeProp" (of type "resultTypes") into a function expecting a 'keyof ResponseData', so it says:

> Argument of type 'resultTypes' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'keyof ResponseData'

```
export interface ResponseData {
   products: string[];
   content: string[];
} 

export type resultTypes = 'categories'| 'products'| 'content'| 'files';

const response: ResponseData = {products: ['r'], content: ['r']}

const currentResultTypes = Object.keys(response) as resultTypes[];

type typeProperty = keyof typeof response;

const hasResultsOfType = (typeProp: typeProperty) => {
  return typeProp in response && response[typeProp];
};

const typeProp = currentResultTypes[0];
const isValid = hasResultsOfType(typeProp);
```

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr313m) what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):

```
type ResultTypes = 'categories' | 'products' | 'content' | 'files';
```

the type you are probably looking for is

```
inferface ResponseData = {
    categories?: string[];
    products?: string[];
    content?: string[];
    files?: string[];
}
```

where each property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) and has a `string[]` value type.

---

You can get the compiler to compute this for you from `ResultTypes` via a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with the "`?`" [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers):

```
type ResponseData = { [K in ResultTypes]?: string[] };
/* type ResponseData = {
    categories?: string[] | undefined;
    products?: string[] | undefined;
    content?: string[] | undefined;
    files?: string[] | undefined;
}*/
```

That's enough to get the rest of your code working, but it's a [`type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) instead of an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces).

---

If you really need to use an `interface`, you can rename the original `type` out of the way and then do an empty [`extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) clause:

```
type _ResponseData = { [K in ResultTypes]?: string[] };
interface ResponseData extends _ResponseData { }
```

It would be nice if you could eliminate the intermediate type alias by substituting in the definition, like

```
interface ResponseData extends { [K in ResultTypes]?: string[] } { } // error
```

but that doesn't work since interfaces are only allowed to extend named types.

Luckily you can still get there: `{[K in X]?: Y}` is equivalent to `Partial<Record<X, Y>>` using the [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) utility types... so we can use the named type `Partial<Record<ResultTypes, string[]>>` directly:

```
interface ResponseData extends Partial<Record<ResultTypes, string[]>> { }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAKuBUC8UDkAxgIbAQDmA9gE4CWCeUAPvmFRQCaIHDwPOEUAdqWF98AMxrJ6AbgBQc0JCgB9OPDBD4EACIkiOKAG8oAbQDSUGoNgIU6TPAC6AfgBcUeMFqCypp1AAvvIA9ABUUErQagiagtp6wAa4RnJQ6VDEpJS0CO6e3tZ+AcyIguwQkoIQ7PIZUKwcXDz5Xj7FTFBlFVU1dRkEQiLArYW+-p3dldZ9aRmS0vCj7ROl5dPVtXKBYSEK1qRU4kQE0OpxCfpQEAAeIuzwqudaulcmgfvCEEcnZ7EviQMt3ujwACkQqMAaERkAAeOCDKjseF2VAYSDwAA0BRWTgAfHjjEEFHIDt9jqcoAB5ChgR7AiDlR4mCxWGzqezohCuDxtIoTQJEwUhELXKhsKgkuSDeLAKBUf7xCAeZ5KwGGEyNTjceAeUx4Kh4JzYmXDPUGo3EmVeTKIcWM4ActGOFWohwYia4fVa5q8JzyRSYSKYUFsSCQkCGADWEBAFHEwcg8fliu0AetcoAFkR4E6eFTxFzDAAKKKh2keMth76gACUOEJqXSCuAdpsVdpbJTGheUAAZH3uxcIKYO2B-dt01o5WPDAQ7QrhHmufBTAAGCcZqzwABqMJo7EM2dzbvgBa5pZDYdrMiAA)